# data reader is incompatible with the specified. does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parameterized-query

I keep getting the below exception. The exception baffles me because I am not selecting `UserID`.

I have tried changing the select to `SELECT *` but this just causes a `result.Count` of 0 regardless if the data exists or not.

I have a dummy record in the Database called bob tob.

I have noticed that if I hover over the Users part of `db.Users.SqlQuery`.

The text inside is

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[userID] AS [userID], 
[Extent1].[userFirstName] AS [userFirstName], 
[Extent1].[userLastName] AS [userLastName], 
[Extent1].[userName] AS [userName], 
[Extent1].[userEmail] AS [userEmail], 
[Extent1].[userPassword] AS [userPassword], 
[Extent1].[userStatus] AS [userStatus], 
[Extent1].[userEmailVerificationStatus] AS [userEmailVerificationStatus], 
[Extent1].[userActivationCode] AS [userActivationCode]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]}
```

I am guessing it's trying to SELECT all of the User class items regardless? If that's true Then how do I stop this? What am I missing?

This is the exception:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'UserRegistrationPasswordsModel.User'. A member of the type, 'userID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Below is the code that calls `EmailExists`. I added the `ToString()` falsely hoping that maybe was the issue.

```
#region EmailExist
// Email already exists?
if (Utilities.EmailExists(user.userEmail.ToString()))
{
    // A pretty awesome way to make a custom exception
    ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Email already exists");

    // Bounce back
    return View(user);
}
#endregion
```

Below is the procedure that is supposed to check if the email exists or not.

```
#region EmailExists
    // Confirm if the Email exists or not
    public static bool EmailExists(string Email)
    {
        bool result = false;
        Models.UserRegistrationPasswordsEntities1 db = new Models.UserRegistrationPasswordsEntities1();
        var queryResult = db.Users.SqlQuery("SELECT userEmail FROM Users WHERE userEmail = @1;", 
                                                                          new SqlParameter("@1", Email)).FirstOrDefault();

        // the ternary opertor is pretty awesome
        result = queryResult.Result.GetType() == null ? false : true;

        return result;
    }
    #endregion
```

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [userID]                      INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [userFirstName]               VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [userLastName]                VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [userName]                    VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [userEmail]                   VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [userPassword]                VARCHAR (100)    NOT NULL,
    [userStatus]                  BIT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [userEmailVerificationStatus] BIT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [userActivationCode]          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [userDateOfBirth]             DATETIME         NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([userID] ASC)
);
```

And this is the `User` model class:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int userID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage ="First name required")]
    public string userFirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Last name required")]
    public string userLastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Username required")]
    public string userName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "email is required")]
    public string userEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime userDateOfBirth { get; set;}


    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Minimum of 6 characters required")]
    public string userPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required")]
    [Compare("userPassword", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password and password do not match")]
    public string userConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public bool userStatus { get; set; }
    public bool userEmailVerificationStatus { get; set; }

    public System.Guid userActivationCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have spent the better part of 2 hours trying to figure this out.

Below are resources I have accessed trying to find a solution.

Any and all help is appreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/advanced-entity-framework-scenarios-for-an-mvc-web-application

https://forums.asp.net/t/1991176.aspx?The+data+reader+is+incompatible+with+the+specified+model

[Incompatible Data Reader Exception From EF Mapped Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235783/incompatible-data-reader-exception-from-ef-mapped-objects)

[The data reader is incompatible with the specified Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791037/the-data-reader-is-incompatible-with-the-specified-entity-framework)

https://forums.asp.net/t/1980259.aspx?I+get+this+error+The+data+reader+is+incompatible+with+the+specified+DBLaxmiTatkalModel+TblAttendence+A+member+of+the+type+AttendenceId+does+not+have+a+corresponding+column+in+the+data+reader+with+the+same+name+

[What can cause an EntityCommandExecutionException in EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785019/what-can-cause-an-entitycommandexecutionexception-in-entitycommanddefinition-exe/30785020)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incompatible Data Reader Exception From EF Mapped Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235783/incompatible-data-reader-exception-from-ef-mapped-objects)

Comment: This is almost a year old, what are you doing?

Comment: "Possible duplicate" is a way to clean-up - to close similar questions and keep one with the best answers. The date is not essential. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha
If you agree that it requires clarification please vote on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281980/add-clarification-link-to-possible-duplicate-automated-comment .
If you see multiple duplicates, you should choose one as canonical and vote to close others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error says:

> A member of the type, 'userID', does not have a corresponding column
>   in the data reader with the same name.

That means results returned by your query do not match type of your entity (`User`). And indeed they do not - your query return single column `userEmail`, while type `User` has much more columns (including `userID` mentioned in error message). Why results should match type `User`? Because you are querying this entity by doing `db.Users.SqlQuery`.

Your query is also wrong (because `'@1'` is not parameter but literal string), but that doesn't matter, because you don't need to use raw sql query here anyway. Just do:

```
public static bool EmailExists(string Email)
{        
    using (var db = new Models.UserRegistrationPasswordsEntities1()) {
        return db.Users.Any(c => c.userEmail == Email);
    }       
}
```

If you want to issue arbitrary sql queries (though I should say once again that in this case there is absolutely no reason to do this) - use `db.Database.SqlQuery`:

```
using (var db = new Models.UserRegistrationPasswordsEntities1()) {
    var email = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
        "SELECT userEmail FROM Users WHERE userEmail = @email",
        new SqlParameter("email", Email))
    .FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I rapped that in single quotes seeing if it was  a quirk of Entity. I appreciate your response, but I would really like to do this with a parameterized query so I can have some security from Sql Injection.

Comment: @user3119737 Entity Framework queries are already parametrized. So query shown in my example is already sql-injection safe.

Comment: really? Not that I don't believe you, but do you have any supporting documentation on that? I just did a quick google search and came up with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations. It specifically states that Entity Queries are not safe from Sql Injection attacks and you should build queries with Parameters.

Comment: Well sure they are, who would have used Entity Framework at all if that were not the case? `db.Users.Any(c => c.userEmail == Email)` will be converted to parameterized query similar to yours (but better).

Comment: That article says about Entity SQL. That's different thing from what is shown in answer. Entity SQL is entity framework specific sql-like language which you almost never need to use in practice.

Comment: Like this? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-with-edm.aspx . See below Linq Query Syntax.

Comment: That's not Entity SQL if you ask that. That's LINQ query, which is sql-injection-safe in entity framework (same as I use in my answer).

Comment: If you are still in doubt, do `db.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine` and observe queries generated by EF in console while you are making LINQ queries.

Comment: Punch me in the face. it was @1. :facepalm:. I will do what you said and look at the db.Database.log. Thank you very much. I spent so much time on such a stupid typo.