# Join two tables issue in linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am developing a web portal for reports and updates..
For displaying records..
I am passing id from controller parameters..

If am fetching data from one table it is working fine..
Eg

```
Var employee = slp.urlt.where ( x=> x.Id == Id).ToList ();
```

But when i am joining with another table it gives error

```
var result = from ut in slp.urlt
                     join ct in slp.Cities on ut.City equals ct.Id
                     where ut.Id == Id
                     select new
                     {
                         ut.R_Name_Enn,
                         ut.R_Name_Arr,
                         ut.R_Addr_Enn,
                         ut.R_Addr_Arr,
                         ct.Id,
                         ct.Name,
                         ct.Name_Arr
                     };
```

So i was check with sql .. following query working fine in sql ..

```
SELECT A.R_name_e,A.R_name_a,A.R_addr_e,A.R_addr_a,B.Id,B.Name,B.Name_ar FROM urlt A inner join City B on A.City = B.Id WHERE A.Id = 90000001
```

Comment: Can you share the error it's throwing

Comment: Execution exceptions was unhandled by user code

Comment: It seems the issue is in your DB. Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785019/what-can-cause-an-entitycommandexecutionexception-in-entitycommanddefinition-exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you have a `DbContext` with `Employees` and `Cities`. Every `Employee` lives in a `City`; every `City` is the residence of zero or more `Employees`. Clearly a simple one-to-many relation using a foreign key.

Following the [entity framework code-first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) you would have something similar to the following classes:

```
class City
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every city Houses zero or more Employees:
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}

class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Employee lives in exactly one City, using foreign key
    public int CityId {get; set;}
    public virtual City {get; set;}
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<City> Cities {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
}
```

Because I follow the entity framework code first conventions, entity framework will capable to detect the tables and the columns and the one-to-many relation between the City and the Employees.

Only if you want to use non-default names for tables, or columns, you'll need Attributes or fluent API.

### Back to your question

> Given an `Id` you want several properties of the `Employee` with this
>   `Id`, inclusive several properties of the `City` that houses this
>   `Employee`

You could use a join. However, if you use the `City` property, then entity framework is smart enough to understand which join is needed. The code looks much more natural to the reader:

```
var queryEmployees = myDbcontext.Employees   // from the sequence of all Employees
    .Where(employee => employee.Id == Id)    // keep only the employee with this Id
    .Select(employee => new                  // from the remaining employees
    {                                        // make one new object with properties:
        NameEnn = employee.R_Name_Enn,
        NameArr = ut.R_Name_Arr,
        AddrEnn = ut.R_Addr_Enn,
        AddrArr = ut.R_Addr_Arr,            
        City = new                           // I chose to make a sub-property for city
        {                                     // if desired, you can flatten it.
            Id = employee.City.Id,
            Name = employee.City.Name,
            NameArr = employee.City.Name_Arr,
        },
    });
```

I expect there will only be one employee with this Id. To fetch this one Employee use:

```
var fetchedEmployee = queryEmployees.FirstOrDefault();
```

or if you really want a list with this one `Employee`:

```
var fetchedEmployees = queryEmployees.ToList();
```

If you really think that a join is more readable, and better maintainable - which I doubt - You can get the same result using an inner join:

```
var queryEmployees = myDbcontext.Employees   // from the sequence of all Employees
    .Where(employee => employee.Id == Id)    // keep only the employee with this Id
    .Select(employee => new                  // join the remaining employees
    .Join(myDbcontext.Cities,                // with the sequence of Cities
    employee => employee.CityId,             // from each Employee take the CityId
    city => city.Id                          // from each City take the Id,
    (employee, city) => new                  // when they match 
    {                                        // make one new object with properties:
        NameEnn = employee.R_Name_Enn,
        NameArr = ut.R_Name_Arr,
        AddrEnn = ut.R_Addr_Enn,
        AddrArr = ut.R_Addr_Arr,            
        City = new
        {
            Id = city.Id,
            Name = city.Name,
            NameArr = city.Name_Arr,
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to place or convert your query to list. Place to list in the end .

```
var result = (from ut in slp.urlt
                     join ct in slp.Cities on ut.City equals ct.Id
                     where ut.Id == Id
                     select new
                     {
                         ut.R_Name_Enn,
                         ut.R_Name_Arr,
                         ut.R_Addr_Enn,
                         ut.R_Addr_Arr,
                         ct.Id,
                         ct.Name,
                         ct.Name_Arr
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Getting error like.. entity command execution exception was unhandled by user code